# Flutter based Android app throwing MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method on channel)

Tags: java, android, flutter, dart

I am trying to make the native side of my android app to communicate with Flutter.

This is on the Flutter side:

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('getHallInfo');

@override
void initState() {
testing().then((String lst) {
  setState(() {
    if (lst != null) str = lst;
  });
});

super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
  children: <Widget>[Text(str)],
);
}

static Future<String> testing() async {
String lst;
try {
  lst = await platform.invokeMethod('getHalls');
} catch (e) {
  print(e.toString());
}

return lst;
}
```

And this is on the native Java:

```
private static final String CHANNEL = "getHallInfo";
super.configureFlutterEngine(getFlutterEngine());
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(getFlutterEngine());

new MethodChannel(getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {

            if (methodCall.method.equals("getHalls")) {
              String mm= "Succeeded";
              System.out.println("Entered");
                result.success(mm);
            }

        }
    });
```

My Pubspec.yaml:

```
name: flutterModule

description: A new flutter module project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
 sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
 flutter:
  sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

flutter_svg: ^0.17.4

google_fonts: ^1.1.0

intl: ^0.16.1

dev_dependencies:
 flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter

flutter:
 uses-material-design: true
assets:
- assets/icons/

module:
 androidX: true
 androidPackage: com.example.flutterModule
 iosBundleIdentifier: com.example.flutterModule
```

This is the error I get:

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getHalls on channel getHallInfo)

**Note:** "Entered" is shown on the terminal

**Edit:** These are the things that I tried:

1. Run flutter clean
2. Run flutter upgrade
3. Restart the app

But this exception persists.

Comment: @PeterHaddad I've updated the code with CHANNEL's value

Comment: Just asking you are referring to these [add-to-app docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android) ?

Comment: @dev-aentgs Yes. The app was working fine until I tried to exchange data between the native part and the Flutter part. Interestingly, the native part receives the correct data but fails to send any.

Answer (score 1):

you just have to stop the app and restart it again.

make sure you did `pub get` before you stop your app.
use the command .

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: I've followed these steps. But unfortunately, the problem is still there.

Comment: try ` flutter clean` in terminal

Comment: try running - `flutter doctor`

Comment: there may be some spelling error in your code or in you might have imported wrong package

Comment: Try upgrading you package

Comment: Hi. I've looked for spelling errors, but found none. I've also followed the instructions you gave. But the problem isn't solved.

Comment: is your system online.

Comment: try `flutter run -v`

Comment: in your pubspec.yaml  file check, the package is placed in the right place

Comment: I've tried both. Unfortunately the exception is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Try `flutter clean`

then `flutter upgrade`

then `flutter run -v`

If that doesn't work, have a look at the following issues:
[issue01](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter_cached_network_image/issues/50),
[issue02](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10912)

I hope this will help you

Comment: I've followed these steps. The problem is still there.

Comment: I've added some links. I hope that will help you solve your problem.

Comment: I've gone through both links and followed those instructions. But it still throws the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to run

```
Flutter clean
```

then  again  restart/run  your app

Comment: some of the time same error occurs in my projects by using this  flutter clean command and restart android  studio i solve my problem, may be this is some other important issue, thank  for your kind time.